# Compressing a ton of same-sized bitmap images and transfer them on IOS

Tags: ios, image-processing

I have been doing some image processing on iphone. After casting some magic on the RGBA32 bitmap images I captured from camera, I would like to save and transfer them. My headache is that the iphone is quite slow at compressing the images with

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation()
```

, costing about 400ms per image on iphone6 at full photo resolution if my measurement is correct. I am trying to cut this overhead down and hope the following detailed descriptions of my situation may help:

1. As I have measured, the compressing is the bottle neck of the pipeline. I have chosen a very short exposure time and all other processing is fast;
2. I take the shot from camera as bitmap, do some custom processing on pixel-level (<100ms) then decides saving it or not based on my processing outcome. In most cases (~80%), I throw it away, so saving directly as jpeg from camera would make throughput worse;
3. My processing only need the grey-scale version of the color image, so I guess using a different bitmap format (YUV) may help but I doubt that would make things dramatically different;
4. All of my images are of the **same resolution** and I do not need to view them in a regular image viewer, so I am free to **encode them as I like**;
5. I would take about 1000 shots-to-be-saved (ignoring those discarded) sequentially, so buffering them all in memory is not feasible;
6. I have done some cute stuff on GPGPU with openGLES so I bet it can help, but it would certainly bring a lot of pain so I would like to find short cuts.

Any input is much appreciated!